# Replacing a char in a char array not working from a variable

Tags: arrays, c, char

I am trying to write a program that takes in 5 characters then takes in a number and a letter and switches the character at the index/number to the new character. I think I have it but it is not working and defaulting the number to 0.

Also, is there a way to get both inputs at the same time?

```
  char str[5];
  int index;
  char temp;
  printf("Enter five characters\n");
  scanf("%s", str);
  printf("Please enter a number.\n");
  scanf("%d", &index);
  printf("Please enter a letter.\n");
  scanf("%s", &temp);
  str[index - 1] = temp;
  printf("The five characters are now %s\n", str);
```

accessing the char array with the index variable is giving me the first element always.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: ```temp``` is a character variable. The format specifier for a ```char``` variable is ```%c```, not ```%s```.

Comment: Problems: Not enough space for the null byte. Your code isn't checking the return value of scanf either.

Comment: `char str[5];`: this can contain only 4 characters, you need one more for the null terminator (read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book).

Comment: "takes in a number and a letter and switches the character at the index/number to the new character." --> is unclear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Kindly restate.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I haven't code in C for a long, long time; however, I did run this code below successfully. You might have to review it and fix other things I might have missed.

First, we will change the first `scanf` by indicating we want only 5 characters `scanf("%5c", str);` and I'm indicating we want the last position in the array to have.

Next, we will do a for loop because we want to only accept an index between 1 to 5.

Finally, and this is important, we change the `scanf` to get one character; however, this isn't intuitive as before, because you need a space before the character indicator: `scanf(" %c", &temp);`

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[5];
    
    printf("Enter five characters\n");
    scanf("%5c", str);
    
    int index = -1;
    while (index < 1 || index > sizeof(str)){
        printf("Please enter a number 1 to %d.\n", (int) sizeof(str));
        scanf("%d", &index);
    }
    
    char temp;
    printf("Please enter a letter.\n");
    scanf(" %c", &temp);
    
    str[index - 1] = temp;
    printf("The five characters are now %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```bash
Enter five characters
12345
Please enter a number 1 to 5.
1
Please enter a letter.
x
The five characters are now x2345


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char str[5];
    int index;
    char temp;

    printf("Enter five characters\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Please enter a number.\n");
    scanf("%d", &index);
    printf("Please enter a letter.\n");
    scanf(" %c", &temp);
    str[index - 1] = temp;
    printf("The five characters are now %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter five characters
12345
Please enter a number.
2
Please enter a letter.
x
The five characters are now 1x345
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: This is logically correct, but has functional problem, as `str` is not `NULL` terminated. Also `index` can be out of bound as there is no boundary check.